# pale colours turning into loud colours

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, adobe-photoshop-elements

i've been having a hard time with Photoshop. i'm a student in a games and web design course and i can't do any work for them on my Photoshop for what it is doing. I use Photoshop elements 6.0

here's what it's doing, i'm using a pale colour (like #ffdcff) when i use it it turns into a hot pink colour (#ff05fc) it's not only pink it's any pale colour i use get turned into a loud colour.

how do i fix it?

Comment: Karina, please explain what you are doing when you are using the colour?
Is it when you save a picture and you use in a webpage? Or is it while working with PS and you type in a colour value and i turns into a bright colour?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are working with a file format such as gif or png that uses (or can use) a colour table and has less than 24 Bit colour depth. Check if you have RGB or CMYK checked under Image > Mode (Thats in Photoshop - don't know about PS Elements). Set to RGB or CMYK if it is set to Index.

Comment: So Karina, any news? Did it work out for you?